# PHP + Apache Basic HTTP authentication/limit users to specific directories

Tags: php, apache, security, http, authentication

I'd like to have logged in users access to certain directories only. For example, have the following directory structure:

> /stuff/user-a/pic.jpg
>
> /stuff/user-b/file.doc

I'd like Apache to only give user-a access to `/stuff/user-a` and give a 403 if he tries to reach `/stuff/user-b`

Now, I've been reading and it seems to be possible to do this with REMOTE_USER and mod_rewrite. Which will make it even better, as i could rewrite it as `/stuff -> /stuff/$REMOTE_USER`

The problem is, I don't want the ugly browser popup. My PHP application already has a login form and a session. From what I've been reading, it is possible to use basic HTTP authentication as an auth method for PHP (to login as http://user:pass@stackoverflow.com). But the opposite (passing a web form to the HTTP authentication) doesn't seem to be possible.

I would also like to avoid using something as mod_xsendfile, as I'd rather not use any "proxy" scripts to handle this, and let Apache take care of access.

Comment: So if you already have a PHP application login, why try to use Apache's rudimentary basic authentication for access control rather than simply implement a simple access control scheme in PHP?